# Best way to pass nullable between client-server

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, nullable

Let’s say I have double length that can be either a real length or not ready yet since we got no length yet in the server and there is nothing to send to the client. We need to pass this length from the server to the client as part of a fixed data protocol. The client currently uses the length only once, but might use it more than that in the future.

1. Pass double length and bool isLengthValid, and in every place you use length, check if isLengthValid
   -Clean design without mixing data types but user have to remember to check
2. Pass double? length, and in every place you use length, check if length==null
   -Design is clear (since it’s a nullable) but if you look and the type. Also – there will be an exception if someone uses without checking (good and bad, depends how you look at it)
3. Make a class Length instead of double. The class will have a clear interface of GetLengthIfYouCheckedIt or something.
   Very readable and hard to make mistakes but design is a little over done.

What is your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say option2:

- What you want is precisely why nullables were introduced.
- Instead of adding a method to check wether it's a valid number or not, you'd use the built-in `Nullable<double>.HasValue`, just as it was meant for it.
- Making a class for Length makes it doubly closed: it's only for LENGTH and it holds a `Double`. Think of how many of such classes you'll have to make and maintain for TIME/`DateTime`, MONEY/`Decimal` etc. It will never end.
- The option 1 is just your own rolled `Nullable<T>` rewrapped with another name.

In other words, enforce the DRY principle, and use [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ;)

HTH,

Bab.

Answer (score 2):

I'd pass a `double?`. That's essentially a double + a bool value indicating if it's valid so using the 1) option would just be reinventing nullable. I think that the 3) option is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

My advise would be that use nullable  like this public Double? Length;

You will get methods like Length.HasValue, and Length.Value this will make the code easy to read and quicker for you to use( i mean no need to write new class etc by quicker for you)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep it as a length parameter but return `-1`?

Comment: That's introducing an implicit non-standard convention into the codebase. Can be most confusing to any uninitiated developers reading the code and worse, can cause logic bugs should -1 someday become a legitimate value for the field.

Comment: @urig - Disagree, there is nothing wrong with returning `-1` as the return value as long as it's documented that's what it represents. If that was the case then how would you know that `String.IndexOf` will return `-1` instead of null? **You read the documentation**....also I think your comment regarding the length is clutching at straws, nothing can be of length -1 it's a pointless value within the given context, hence why it's suitable for this situation to represent an `undefined` state.

Comment: Disagree :). Far better to rely on conventions and make life easier for your consumers than to tell them to RTFM.

Comment: @urig - I think we can just agree to disagree. You keep mentioning "*conventions*", however, `null` could mean various things from a web services point of view e.g. something went wrong with the call. I am not saying you should always opt for `-1` over `null` as 9x out of 10 `null` *is* the correct value to return. However, in *this particular scenario* -1 is just as good.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would suggest making the request async, so that you do not return anything to the client until the data is actually ready.

If that is not possible, go with the second option.

Comment: It's part of a bigger data contract